# How to avoid generating crc files and SUCCESS files while saving a DataFrame?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code to save a spark DataFrame to JSON file

```
unzipJSON.write.mode("append").json("/home/eranw/Workspace/JSON/output/unCompressedJson.json")
```

the output result is:

```
part-r-00000-704b5725-15ea-4705-b347-285a4b0e7fd8
.part-r-00000-704b5725-15ea-4705-b347-285a4b0e7fd8.crc
part-r-00001-704b5725-15ea-4705-b347-285a4b0e7fd8
.part-r-00001-704b5725-15ea-4705-b347-285a4b0e7fd8.crc
_SUCCESS
._SUCCESS.crc
```

1. How do I generate a single JSON file and not a file per line?
2. How can I avoid the *crc files?
3. How can I avoid the SUCCESS file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want a single file, you need to do a `coalesce` to a single partition before calling write, so:

```
unzipJSON.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").json("/home/eranw/Workspace/JSON/output/unCompressedJson.json")
```

Personally, I find it rather annoying that the number of output files depend on number of partitions you have before calling `write` - especially if you do a `write` with a `partitionBy` - but as far as I know, there are currently no other way.

I don't know if there is a way to disable the .crc files - I don't know of one - but you can disable the _SUCCESS file by setting the following on the hadoop configuration of the Spark context.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
```

Note, that you may also want to disable generation of the metadata files with:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

Apparently, generating the metadata files takes some time (see [this blog post](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/the-bleeding-edge-spark-parquet-and-s3/)) but aren't actually that important (according to [this](http://search-hadoop.com/m/q3RTtrwSwe2hVzCu&subj=Re+Parquet+writing+gets+progressively+slower)). Personally, I always disable them and I have had no issues.

Comment: The question is why we need `CRC` and `_SUCCESS` files? Spark (worker) nodes write data simultaneously and these files act as checksum for validation. Writing to a single file takes away the idea of distributed computing and this approach may fail if your resultant file is too large.

Comment: `_metadata` will not create since [this spark jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15719) merge to spark master and spark-2.0, [related PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13455)

Answer (score 7):

Ignore crc files on .write

```
val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
fs.setWriteChecksum(false)
```

Comment: This worked for me. I wanted to keep `_SUCCESS` file, but suppress writing `.crc` files.

Answer (score 6):

Just a little update in above answer. To disable crc and SUCCESS file, simply set property in spark session as follows(example)

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
```

Comment: tx, but it doesn't suppress crc files

Comment: @Juh_ Did you find any solution so that .crc file won't be created?

Comment: No sorry, i ditn't investigate further