# Pandas: how to read-in a disaggregated JSON file?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a `JSON` file exported from `Spark` that has a weird structure.

The data is exported using `spark_write_json(df, 'file:///mypath/myfile')`, where `df` is a Spark dataframe.

What I see in my path is a folder name `myfile` containing thousands of small `.part_somenumbers.crc` files such as

- `.part-0000.crc`
- `.part-0001.crc`
- etc

How can I read these into Pandas? Is that even a correct JSON output?

Comment: You may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382612/how-to-avoid-generating-crc-files-and-success-files-while-saving-a-dataframe). Can your Pandas DF fit into the RAM of a single node? If so you can convert your Spark DF to Pandas DF using SparkDF.toPandas() method

Comment: @MaxU thanks. Nope, I can only work with this output unfortunately. Is that even a proper json? do you know how to process that?

Comment: "part-XXXX.crc" - are HDFS partitions of your JSON file. Did you check docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets ? You can read JSON from HDFS to Spark DataFrame, which has `.toPandas()` method...

Comment: huummm I am using `sparklyr` to process the data in Spark

Comment: Why don't you export those files into another format since you have the hand on your sparklyr jobs ?

Comment: @eliasah because `csv` wont work... and I dont see another easy format. Any ideas?

Comment: Parquet is a great columnar based solution.

Comment: would that work with Pandas?

Comment: With the proper tools yes (pyarrow) Again like mentioned in the other comment, you can use spark with python and collect to pandas...

Comment: @eliasah yeah but I dont wanna do that. Already getting the setup right with sparklyr was a pain

Comment: Because with all due respect to sparklyr it isn't a production ready tool. It's also missing lots of functionalities from spark. Yes it provides a nice dplyr wrapper for spark DataFrame but it has so many restraints... that's your choice in the end.

Comment: @eliasah, in R you would recommend sparkR? what is the most mature between Python/R to interact with R and avoid JAVA at all costs?

Comment: To avoid java/scala at all costs, I'd go with python. Scala is the most mature thought with spark. Sparklyr is a nice toy but it's still a toy.