# How to avoid generation meta files (.crc files) in Spark for text files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, crc

I writing an RDD to the local file system in text format by using the saveAsTextFile method.
In the output directory, there is one .crc file for each part file even for the _SUCCESS file.

I am just looking for any inbuilt functionality or property of Hadoop/Spark that avoid generation of these metafiles(especially .crc)

[I found following properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382612/how-to-avoid-generating-crc-files-and-success-files-while-saving-a-dataframe) to avoid _SUCCESS file generation and .crc file generation for parquet file but looking for similar property for text file.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the parquet setting just to see if it would work? That is the only thing I've seen so far even related to these .crc files.

Comment: Have you tried `sc.hadoopConfigurtion.setBoolean("fs.file.impl.disable.cache", true)`?