# How to avoid/disable .crc files for writing csv files in sparklyr?

Tags: r, csv, amazon-s3, sparklyr

I am writing spark data frame to local file system as a csv file by using the spark_write_csv function. In the output directory, there is one .crc file for each part file.

I am looking for any functions or property of Hadoop/Spark that avoid generation of these .crc files.

```
flights_tbl<-copy_to(sc,flights,"flights")
spark_write_csv(flights_tbl,  path="xxx" , mode = "overwrite")
```

This is the output i get:

```
.part-00000-365d53be-1946-441a-8e25-84cb009f2f45-c000.csv.crc

part-00000-365d53be-1946-441a-8e25-84cb009f2f45-c000
```

Comment: Related to [How to avoid generating crc files and SUCCESS files while saving a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34382612/8371915)

Comment: The .crc files are more likely related to the output storage system instead of Hadoop/Spark setting. Here is a simple test. Running spark locally and saving a simple DataFrame to local storage and S3 respectively, you will see that there are .crc files in local output folder, but there is no .crc file in S3 output folder. The two cases used the same Hadoop/Spark settings of the local system.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. Checksum files are generated for all Spark Data Sources and built-in legacy RDD API and the behavior is not configurable.

To avoid it completely you'd have:

- Implement your own Hadoop Input format.
- Or implement your own Data Source (v1 or v2) which doesn't depend on Hadoop input formats.

and add `spakrlyr` wrappers to expose in R codebase.

Comment: Thank you. So crc files wont create any problem when writing the spark data frame to S3 using sparklyr?

Comment: not when writing to s3, but AFAICT they will mess things up if you're loading into Redshift.

Comment: also, it seems like there must be a way, because EMR does not generate these files.