# Spark - How to change the name of the coalesced parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, databricks

So, when writing parquet files to s3, I'm able to change the directory name using the following code:

```
spark_NCDS_df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(s3locationC1+"parquet")
```

Now, when I output this, the contents within that directory are as follows:

[image]

I'd like to make two changes:

- Can I update the file name for the `part-0000....snappy.parquet` file?
- Can I output this file without the `_SUCCESS`, `_committed` and `_started` files?

The documentation i've found online hasn't been very helpful.

Comment: Spark SQL doesn't support name customization (you have to rename the result) and the second question looks like a duplicate of [How to avoid generating crc files and SUCCESS files while saving a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34382612/8371915)

Comment: The command `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")` gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'RemoteContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'`

Comment: Why not just have a post processing step, use `dbutils` to cleanup and rename?

Answer (score 2):

```
    out_file_name = snappy.parquet
    path = "mnt/s3locationC1/"
    tmp_path = "mnt/s3locationC1/tmp_data"
    df = spark_NCDS_df

    def copy_file(path,tmp_path,df,out_file_name):
      df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(tmp_path)
      file = dbutils.fs.ls(tmp_path)[-1][0]
      dbutils.fs.cp(file,path+out_file_name)
      dbutils.fs.rm(tmp_path,True)

   copy_file(path,tmp_path,df,out_file_name)
```

This function copy and paste your required output file to the destination and then delete the temp files, all the _SUCCESS, _committed and _started removed with it.

If you need anything more, please let me know.